# GCP Global ALB with ssl termination stops sending traffic after ddos

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

We had a black hat person taking down our website with DDOS. Our infrastructure looks like this

Cloudflare -> GCP ALB -> Internet NEG -> External PaaS

Cloudflare started reporting 503 and stopped hitting our backend during the attack. When the attack was over, our GCP ALB continued to respond with 502, copied below.

The ALB never recovered, I had to manually remove the Network endoint from the Internet NEG and re-add it. Why did the Internet NEG stop working?

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>502 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You can find additional details in the logs. Search for 502 on this page. There is a section that explains the logging keys to review. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#troubleshoot_general_connectivity_issues

Comment: 100ks of errors on the backend, I see one 502 in the logs. It seems that ALB does not record logs sent to an external NEG.